# How to make backtab skip inputs

Tags: jquery, html, tabs

Typically when you back tab it will go to the last input. What if you wanted to skip an input that had a specific class on it?

I have this working forward just not backwards. This is the code I am using to attempt to tab backward:

http://jsfiddle.net/cjonp23e/

Here is the code to go forward:

```
else if (e.keyCode == 9) //TAB
{
    jqueryTarget.next().focus();
    return true;
}
```

How can I tab backwards in the same way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NO Need for any `jQuery`. Just add: `tabindex="-1"` to each `button`, they will be ignored

See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cjonp23e/38/